# How can I pass selected checkboxlist values to another form?

Tags: javascript, c#

I want to pass selected `checkbox list` values and text to another page which will be stored in another form.

As I am new to I am not able to store those values in another form, I want to save values in rows of table present in another form.

**aspx.cs**

```
protected void Submit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string message = "Texts    Values";
        foreach (ListItem item in CheckBoxList1.Items)
        {
            if (item.Selected)
            {
                message += "\\n";
                message += item.Text + "    " + item.Value; ;
            }
        }
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('" + message + "');", true);
```

**aspx code**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Hform.aspx.cs" Inherits="Hform" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">


    <title></title>

   <script type="text/javascript">
       function ValidateCheckBox(checkboxid, errorname) {
           var isChecked = false;
           var ch = document.getElementById(checkboxid);
           var chkButtons = ch.getElementsByTagName("input");
           for (var i = 0; i < chkButtons.length; i++) {
               if (chkButtons[i].checked) {
                   isChecked = true;
                   break;
               }
           }
           if (!isChecked) {
               document.getElementById(errorname).innerHTML = " Please Select One Option *";

               return isChecked;
           }
           else {
               return isChecked;
           }
       }
       function validateallcheckboxlists() {
           var finalcheck = [];
           finalcheck[0] = ValidateCheckBox("<%=CheckBoxList1.ClientID%>", 'errorname');
            finalcheck[1] = ValidateCheckBox("<%=CheckBoxList2.ClientID%>", 'error-name3');
            finalcheck[2] = ValidateCheckBox("<%=CheckBoxList3.ClientID%>", 'error-name4');
            finalcheck[3] = ValidateCheckBox("<%=CheckBoxList4.ClientID%>", 'error-name5');
            finalcheck[4] = ValidateCheckBox("<%=CheckBoxList17.ClientID%>", 'errorname6');
            finalcheck[5] = ValidateCheckBox("<%=CheckBoxList6.ClientID%>", 'error-name7');
            finalcheck[6] = ValidateCheckBox("<%=CheckBoxList20.ClientID%>", 'error-name8');
            finalcheck[7] = ValidateCheckBox("<%=CheckBoxList8.ClientID%>", 'error-name9');
            finalcheck[8] = ValidateCheckBox("<%=CheckBoxList9.ClientID%>", 'error-name10');
            finalcheck[9] = ValidateCheckBox("<%=CheckBoxList10.ClientID%>", 'error-name11');
            finalcheck[10] = ValidateCheckBox("<%=CheckBoxList19.ClientID%>", 'error-name12');
            finalcheck[11] = ValidateCheckBox("<%=CheckBoxList18.ClientID%>", 'errorname13');
            finalcheck[12] = ValidateCheckBox("<%=CheckBoxList13.ClientID%>", 'error-name14');
            finalcheck[13] = ValidateCheckBox("<%=CheckBoxList14.ClientID%>", 'error-name15');
            finalcheck[14] = ValidateCheckBox("<%=CheckBoxList15.ClientID%>", 'error-name16');
            finalcheck[15] = ValidateCheckBox("<%=CheckBoxList16.ClientID%>", 'error-name17');

            for (var i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
                if (finalcheck[i] == false) {
                    alert("Please fill required fields.");
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
</script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function UncheckOthers(objchkbox) {
            //Get the parent control of checkbox which is the checkbox list
            var objchkList = objchkbox.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
            //Get the checkbox controls in checkboxlist
            var chkboxControls = objchkList.getElementsByTagName("input");
            //Loop through each check box controls
            for (var i = 0; i < chkboxControls.length; i++) {
                //Check the current checkbox is not the one user selected
                if (chkboxControls[i] != objchkbox && objchkbox.checked) {
                    //Uncheck all other checkboxes
                    chkboxControls[i].checked = false;
                }
            }
        }
    </script>

    <style type="text/css">
        .auto-style2 {
            width: 962px;
        }

        .auto-style3 {
            width: 477px;
        }

        .auto-style4 {
            width: 100px;
            height: 38px;
        }

        </style>

</head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="JavaScript.js"></script>

<body>
    <form id="form2" runat="server">
        <div style="text-align:center">xyzform

        </div>
        <table id="Table1" runat="server" align="left" class="auto-style7" border="1">
            <tr><td>1</td>
                <td>The ownership of this house:</td>
                <td class="auto-style3">
                      <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" Width="280px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="CheckBoxList1_SelectedIndexChanged" >
                        <asp:ListItem Text="item1" Value="1" onclick="UncheckOthers(this);"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="item2" Value="2" onclick="UncheckOthers(this);"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="item3" Value="3" onclick="UncheckOthers(this);"></asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:CheckBoxList></td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label><span id="errorname" runat="server">  </span>
                </td>


            </tr>
            <tr><td>2</td>
                <td>xyz2</td>
                <td class="auto-style3">

            <th colspan="3">xyz2</th>
            <tr><td>4</td>
                <td>Main resource of Drinking Water:</td>
                <td class="auto-style3">
                    <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList2" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" Width="976px">
                        <asp:ListItem Text="item1" Value="1" onclick="UncheckOthers(this);">
                        </asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="item2" Value="2" onclick="UncheckOthers(this);"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="item3" Value="3" onclick="UncheckOthers(this);"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="item4" Value="4" onclick="UncheckOthers(this);"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="item5" Value="5" onclick="UncheckOthers(this);">
                        </asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="item6" Value="6" onclick="UncheckOthers(this);"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="item7" Value="7" onclick="UncheckOthers(this);"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="item8" Value="8" onclick="UncheckOthers(this);"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Others" Value="9" onclick="UncheckOthers(this);"></asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:CheckBoxList>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server"></asp:Label><span id="error-name3"></span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td>5</td>

                <td class="auto-style3">
                    <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList3" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" Width="567px">
                        <asp:ListItem text="Near" Value="1" onclick="UncheckOthers(this);">
                        </asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem text="In " Value="2" onclick="UncheckOthers(this);">
                        </asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem text="Away" Value="3" onclick="UncheckOthers(this);"></asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:CheckBoxList>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server"></asp:Label><span id="error-name4"></span>
                </td>

        </table>
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

Similarly I have created 13 more lists